# Globally loading packages while using a CellGroup as the default context

Tags: packages, contexts

I have a notebook I wish to set up where the sections are conceptually related to each other. But, I wish to isolate them from each other programmatically, so that they do not interfere with one another. A built-in method of doing this is to set the default context to `CellGroup` so that each group of cells has its own context. However, each section relies on the same set packages, and because one of them is quite large, I do not wish to reload the packages for each section.  An option is to put each section in its own context manually using `Begin` and `End`, but I would rather avoid that if possible. Ideally, though, I would like to be able to load the packages in their own separate section and elevate them to the `` Global` `` (or equivalent) context. Any thoughts on how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 14):

One possibility would be to modify the notebook's stylesheet so that `Input` cells (or a clone) have something like:

```
CellProlog -> ($ContextPath = DeleteDuplicates[Prepend[$ContextPath,"abc`"]])
```

Then your package's context should be available to all the code:

[image]

Comment: Ah, brilliant. That should have occurred to me, +1. What about loading in packages though? ;)

Comment: Possibly the `Prolog` could be a `Needs` statement, though I haven't checked to see if it would actually create symbols in the package context correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Below Brett's answer:

> Ah, brilliant. That should have occurred to me, +1. What about loading in packages though? ;) – rcollyer

Perhaps you know this but Packages are already loaded to a shared context in the sense that doing `` Get["package`"] `` loads the definitions into (typically) the context `` package` ``, and the definitions are available from any other Cell Group by using the fully qualified name.

What remains is getting e.g. `` package` `` into the `$ContextPath`.  Brett's method works if you know the package contexts ahead of time, but we may want to adapt it to use a (true) global list of shared contexts.  For example we could use `` Global`$sharedContexts `` to store any contexts to be shared across Cell Groups and then set `CellProlog` to:

```
($ContextPath = DeleteDuplicates @ Join[Global`$sharedContexts, $ContextPath])
```

Starting with `` Global`$sharedContexts = {}; `` we could then load a package with:

```
<< "Combinatorica`"
AppendTo[Global`$sharedContexts, "Combinatorica`"];
```

Or we could use a custom `Needs`-type function stored in the `` System` `` context (to make it easily accessible), or we could perhaps modify `BeginPackage` like this:

```
Unprotect[BeginPackage]

BeginPackage[con_, x___] /; ! TrueQ[$shrCntxtMod] :=
     Block[{$shrCntxtMod = True},
       BeginPackage[con, x];
       If[
         ValueQ @ $sharedContexts,
     AppendTo[$sharedContexts, con],
         $sharedContexts = {con}
   ]
 ]
```

Which will add *any* context created with `BeginPackage` to `` Global`$sharedContexts ``.

Comment: Hmm, two years and I haven't upvoted this? Bad user. +1

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks for acknowledging. :-)  Sometimes I wonder if anybody read an answer like this with few or no votes.

Comment: I had read it, but I wanted to go through it before I voted on it, and then I forgot about it. :)