# automatically add Global` to $ContextPath for all notebooks when using CellContext->Notebook

Tags: notebooks, contexts, initialization

I have some definitions in my `init.m`.  E.g. my `init.m` contains this:

```
hex[n_]:=BaseForm[n,16];
```

I know that Mathematica puts this in the `` Global` `` context, and in a default configuration, each notebook's `$Context` is `` Global` `` and its `$ContextPath` also contains `` Global` ``.  So my definitions are automatically available in any notebook I create.

However, I prefer the [`CellContext->Notebook`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/853/is-there-a-way-to-separate-variables-between-multiple-notebooks) option so each of my notebooks automatically gets its own private context.  The problem is that this option (obviously) changes `$Context` to something other than `` Global` ``, and it also removes `` Global` `` from `$ContextPath`.  So my `init.m` definitions  are not automatically available in any notebook I create.

Now, I could type `` Global`hex `` when I want to use my `hex` function, or I could do `` AppendTo[$ContextPath, "Global`"] `` in each notebook.  But I would rather have `` Global` `` added to each notebook's `$ContextPath` automatically.

Is there a way to get `` Global` `` into each notebook's `$ContextPath` automatically?  Or is there some other way I can make my personal definitions available to each notebook automatically while using the `CellContext->Notebook` option?

Comment: Duplicate of [Globally loading packages while using a CellGroup as the default context](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9571)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question seems to be slightly different from [Globally loading packages while using a CellGroup as the default context](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9571/121) (which I just posted an answer for).

Probably the simplest method would be to define your `init.m` functions in the `` System` `` context itself as this is always accessible no matter the `CellContext`.  For example:

```
System`hex[n_] := BaseForm[n, 16]
```

Arguably it is not the best practice but if you are strict about starting all function names with lower-case letters this should theoretically not cause any problems.

Another strategy would be to put all your custom functions in a package or custom context (e.g. `` MyTools` ``) and use `CellProlog` as described by Brett Champion in the question linked above to add this context to `$ContextPath` for all cells.

Comment: I guess I will go with using `CellProlog` to append ``"Global`"`` to my `$ContextPath`.  Thanks for your answer.