# Function definitions in init.m don't work

Tags: initialization, autocomplete

I can't get any function defined in `$UserBaseDirectory/Kernel/init.m` to work.
For example:

```
SinDeg[d_] := Sin[d * Degree]; (* Only line in init.m *)
```

Output:

```
SinDeg[90]
(* => SinDeg[90] *)
```

However when copying the code and executing it inside a Mathematica notebook, it works fine:

```
SinDeg[d_] := Sin[d * Degree];
SinDeg[90]
(* => 1 *)
```

The Mathematica front-end can definitely see the function definitions as it displays `SinDeg` as an autocompletion suggestion, when typing `SinD`.

I'm using Mathematica 9 Home Edition on OS X.

Comment: To eliminate the obvious: you have restarted Mathematica after adding this line to init.m?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries yes.

Comment: What do you get when you type `?SinDeg` directly after Mathematica starts up?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I get this error: `Information::notfound: Symbol SinDeg not found. >>`

Comment: Could you check whether you really have an underscore in your definition in the init.m file?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I do.

Comment: Is the notebook you're trying this in completely empty? (I mean the test notebook, not the init.m file)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Yes it is.

Comment: Is it the only open notebook?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Yes.

Comment: Have you made the cells Initialization cells?

Comment: While one can not tell from what you have posted, I suspect that you need to set the cell in the init.m file as an initialization cell.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries -- Really, I don't know how you beat me to that.

Comment: Check this ref page: tutorial/SystemwideDefaults

Comment: @Jagra It's my lucky night. I'm off to bed now. Only 5 hours of sleep before the alarm will sound...

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Didn't work. File contents of the saved `init.m` was `(* ::Package:: *)\n\nSinDeg[d_]:=Sin[d*Degree]; `, where `\n` is a newline.

Comment: Did you see step 7 in the page I referred to? "choose File > Save and select Mathematica Package from the Save as type popup menu."

Comment: I think this has to do with the Notebook's default context setting in the evaluation menu. Could you try setting this to Global and restarting?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries My guess is that this is the case here... A good way to put custom definitions in the init.m would be to use `Begin` and `End` to create an ``"Init`" `` context and append that context to the context path so that the definitions are available regardless of the notebook's context. (better still, use packages)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Setting the default contetxt to `Global` fixed it, however I would like to have it set to `Unique to This Notebook`. Is that possible?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries This seems to explain it: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9571/globally-loading-packages-while-using-a-cellgroup-as-the-default-context

Comment: @Tyilo See my comment above... use a custom context in your init.m and append it to the context path

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has to do with the Notebook's default context setting in the evaluation menu. If it isn't set to `` Global` ``, the definitions made in init.m are not seen.

As rm-rf says, a good way to put custom definitions in the init.m would be to use `Begin` and `End` to create an `` Init` `` context and append that context to the context path so that the definitions are available regardless of the notebook's context. (better still, use packages)